# Replace a subset of rows of dataframe A with rows of dataframe B in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace the values in the rows 500 to 750 in column `col1` in dataframe `df_A` with the values column `col1` of dataframe `df_B` (with altogether 250 rows) in Python Pandas.

I tried doing it like this

```
df_A.col1.iloc[500:750] = df_B.col1
```

But this yields the notorious

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

and the values in `df_A.col1.iloc[500:750]` get replaced by `NaN`s . So how can I do this kind of replacement of several rows with rows from another dataframe in Pandas without using a for-loop?

Comment: df_A.iloc[500:750, 'col1'] = df_B['col1']. And you may have to restart your IDE. I have seen this kind of error without the NaNs on a perfectly valid code. It disappeared after restarting.

Comment: Have a look at DataFrame.update method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use loc instead:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3), columns=['a0','a1','a2'])
dg=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=['b0','b1','b2'])
print('df=', df)
print('\ndg=', dg)

#replacement of [5,8,11] by [1,4,7]
df.loc[1:3, 'a2']=dg.b1.values
print("\ndf (after replacement) \n ",df)
df=    a0  a1  a2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14

dg=    b0  b1  b2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8

df (after replacement) 
     a0  a1  a2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   1
2   6   7   4
3   9  10   7
4  12  13  14
```

Comment: Ok, I see. `.loc` works, because the index consists of consecutive integer labels by default. And one must use `.values` to convert the column into an array. Thank you!